# Javascript heatmap local issue

Tags: javascript, web, frameworks

i have some issues with my code while using heatmap.js. I need to render mouse move heatmap using and then save it to csv. Chrome error now disappeared after changing `heatmap` to `.heatmap` but still rendering nothing. Div now has its fixed size.

```
window.onload = function(){
    var heatmapInstance = h337.create({
        container: document.querySelector('.heatmap'),
        radius: 90
      });
      document.querySelector('.heatmap').onmousemove = function(ev) {
        heatmapInstance.addData({
          x: ev.layerX,
          y: ev.layerY,
          value: 1
        });
      };
}

<script src="heatMapJs/build/heatmap.min.js"></script>

<script src="js/heatMap.js"></script>





<div class="heatmap"> </div>
```

Comment: `document.querySelector('heatmap')` needs to be `document.querySelector('.heatmap')`. I'd also suggest using [eventListeners](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventListener) instead of overwriting the `onload` and `onmousemove` methods since that can result in overwriting existing functionality.

Comment: it worked. Kinda. Now its not working, but showing no error on console.

Comment: Please update your question with the updated code so we can continue to help you debug

Comment: Done. Can u please look at it now?

Comment: Your code seems to work fine, you just need to give the `.heatmap` div a width and a height

Comment: Still not working even after adding width and height.

Comment: I added a snippet to show you that it works, there must be some kind of error preventing yours from working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following snippet seems to work

```js
window.onload = function(){
  var heatmapInstance = h337.create({
    container: document.querySelector('.heatmap'),
    radius: 90
  });
  
  document.querySelector('.heatmap').onmousemove = function(ev) {
    heatmapInstance.addData({
      x: ev.layerX,
      y: ev.layerY,
      value: 1
    });
  };
}
```

```css
.heatmap {
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/heatmap.js/2.0.0/heatmap.min.js"></script>

<div class="heatmap"></div>
```